# Change Linphone to use TCP

Tags: swift, tcp, udp, voip, linphone

I am trying to have Linphone use TCP so my app will receive calls while in background. How can I do it?

I have tried this code but it didn't work:

```
    var transport = LCSipTransports()
    linphone_core_get_sip_transports(lc, &transport)
    transport.tls_port = PortHere
    linphone_core_set_sip_transports(lc, &transport)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define other ports with value 0 as given below:

```
LCSipTransports transportValue={0};

transportValue.tcp_port=0;

transportValue.udp_port=0;

transportValue.tls_port=tlsport;

linphone_core_set_sip_transports(lc, &transportValue);
```